# How to delete repeated pair of items from a dataframe where ordering doesn't count as unique pair of element

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get the unique combination of col for each docId. For example from the table below i am considering the first row docId: 3, col:[motorbike,boat]  and second row docId: 3, col:[boat,motorbike] to be duplicate and store only one combination of motorbike and boat for docId 3.

The dataframe that i have is

| docId | col |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | motorbike, boat |
| 3 | boat, motorbike |
| 3 | plane, boat |
| 3 | plane, motorbike |
| 3 | motorbike, plane |
| 3 | boat, plane |
| 2 | boat, motorbike |
| 2 | motorbike, boat |
| 1 | motorbike, plane |
| 1 | plane, motorbike |

and the expected dataframe is

| docId | col |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | motorbike, boat |
| 3 | plane, boat |
| 3 | plane, motorbike |
| 2 | motorbike, boat |
| 1 | plane, motorbike |

Comment: can you share the schema of dataframe?

Comment: The schema of database is


 |-- docId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- word1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- word2: string (nullable = true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply `split` the `column` to `array` and sort it then use drop duplicates as below

```
df.withColumn("split", array_sort(split($"col", ", ")))
    .dropDuplicates(Seq("docId", "split"))
    .drop("split")
    .show(false)
```

Result:

```
+-----+----------------+
|docId|col             |
+-----+----------------+
|3    |plane, motorbike|
|2    |boat, motorbike |
|3    |plane, boat     |
|3    |motorbike, boat |
|1    |motorbike, plane|
+-----+----------------+
```

**Updated:**
If you have column as struct then you can convert to array as

```
df2.withColumn("split", array_sort(array("col.word1", "col.word2")))
   .dropDuplicates(Seq("docId", "split"))
   .drop("split")
   .show(false)
```

Output:

```
+-----+------------------+
|docId|col               |
+-----+------------------+
|3    |{plane, motorbike}|
|2    |{boat, motorbike} |
|3    |{plane, boat}     |
|3    |{motorbike, boat} |
|1    |{motorbike, plane}|
+-----+------------------+
```

Comment: Sorry, The Schema of dataframe is

 |-- docId: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- word1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- word2: string (nullable = true)


there was small mistake in the question while creating the table. The element in col is Struct(String, String)